# Thread hangs on DriverManager.getConnection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a multithreaded program that's supposed to run 24/7, sometimes I would see a few threads would just hang after some time the program runs, no exception or error. It just would not do anything. I ran a thread dump to see what the problem and this is the related threaddump for the thread which was not doing anything

```
"Thread2" prio=6 tid=0x0000000014814000 nid=0xbf8 runnable [0x00000000159fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:272)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:269)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:106)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:123)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at database.Database.isItInDatabase(Database.java:1108)
        at miner.Miner.run(Miner.java:145)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and below is the Database method

```
public Boolean isItInDatabase(String userName) throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Boolean exists = false;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://MYSERVERIP:5432/" + database, username, password); //--->>>>>>line 1108
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listing_info where listing_url = ?");
        pst.setString(1, userName);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            exists = rs.getBoolean(1);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        pst.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    return exists;
}
```

I have marked where line 1108 is in my Database file. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? so the program does not wait there forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has nothing to do with databases.  that is a hung socket connection.  it happens when the socket connection gets broken.  the only way to stop it from hanging is to use socket read timeouts.  looks like there are some [jdbc driver config properties](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/connect.html) for postgresql which will fix the issue.